# SQL query returning less records than it should

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query:

```
SELECT ea.Data_Source_ID
FROM eloquaActual as ea
WHERE ea.Data_Source_ID =(select eff.Data_Source_ID
FROM eloquaFromFile eff 
WHERE eff.Permission_Bingo = ea.Permission_Bingo)
```

This should return me all values which their `Data_Source_ID` matches but their `Permission_Bingo` don't. Unfortunately it returns me just 2 records. What is not true. That means my query is written wrong, but what there is wrong?

NOTE: Everything is considered as `VARCHAR` I guess, not 100% sure.
Also note that when I used `WHERE Permission_Bingo=0` it did not return me anything I had to put that zero onto quotes: `WHERE Permission_Bingo='0'`, but with variables of same type it should work ok.

Comment: Could you please add a sqlfiddle link?

Comment: What is sqlfiddle link?

Comment: something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d65a/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
SELECT ea.Data_Source_ID
FROM eloquaActual as ea
WHERE exists (SELECT *
FROM eloquaFromFile eff 
WHERE eff.Permission_Bingo = ea.Permission_Bingo and
ea.Data_Source_ID = eff.Data_Source_ID)
```

Comment: This query is the same as author wrote, they definitely have the same execution plan.

Comment: @zaratustra These queries are different; SQLite ignores surplus rows in scalar subqueries.

Comment: @CL. Thank you, I didn't know about this implicit behavior in SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

Change

WHERE ea.Data_Source_ID =

to

WHERE ea.Data_Source_ID IN

Comment: I doubt it matters, if there are more than one row, he has had to receive an error already.

Comment: He is right, it is not the answer but equals replaced with in helped me a lot, thats why you get my +1. Thanks.